# Fragment - E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android

I've tried nearly everything but the Recycleview is not showing up on screen. I keep getting this error 'E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout'. Been trying to fix this on and off for a couple of days now.

As a side note I am using a Fragment, which is probably why is this giving me hell.

uploadsFragment.java

```
private RecyclerView mRecylcerView;
    private ImageAdapter mAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressCircle;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private List<Upload> mUploads;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uploads, container, 
false);

        mRecylcerView = 
        (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        mRecylcerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecylcerView.setLayoutManager(new 
LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mProgressCircle =                                     
        (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circle2);
    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                mUploads.add(upload);
            }

            mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), mUploads);
            mRecylcerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mRecylcerView.setLayoutManager(new 
            LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            mRecylcerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),databaseError.getMessage(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> mUploads;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> upload){
    mContext = context;
    mUploads = upload;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder, int i) {
    Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(i);
    imageViewHolder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
    Picasso.get()
            .load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl())
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imageViewHolder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView textViewName;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the context form `viewGroup ` instead of passing the activity context ? (`mContext`) on `onCreateViewHolder`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up adapter with RecyclerView after getting response from firebase query.

1. So first make sure that your firebase query returns successful response.
2. Check if "mUploads" list is not blank after getting response.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, viewGroup, false);` with : 
`LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_item, viewGroup, false);`

Plus place your code in your `onViewCreated` instead of `onCreateView`